# Laravel wants to show welcome page, although '/' route is defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm learning Laravel, and after completing [this to-do task tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart), my app still continued to show the default Welcome page.

Just in case that was a mechanism for developers to get rid of default content, i also deleted the `resources/views/welcome.blade.php` file. But it didn't help. All that's changed now is that I get:

> InvalidArgumentException
>   View [welcome] not found.

thrown by `FileViewFinder`.

My route is defined, as per the tutorial, in `app/Http/routes.php`, as:

```
/**
 * Display all tasks
 */
Route::get('/', function(){
    $tasks = Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

    return view('tasks', [
        'tasks' => $tasks
    ]);
});
```

And the view is created in `resources/views/layouts/tasks.blade.php`.

I don't know what's missing...

Full stack trace:

```
InvalidArgumentException thrown with message "View [welcome] not found."
Stacktrace:
#51 InvalidArgumentException in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137
#50 Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder:findInPaths in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:79
#49 Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder:find in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php:128
#48 Illuminate\View\Factory:make in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:971
#47 view in /var/www/Laravel/default/routes/web.php:15
#46 Illuminate\Routing\Router:{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:191
#45 Illuminate\Routing\Route:runCallable in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:165
#44 Illuminate\Routing\Route:run in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:610
#43 Illuminate\Routing\Router:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
#42 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:41
#41 Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings:handle in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#40 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#39 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:67
#38 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken:handle in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#37 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#36 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php:49
#35 Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession:handle in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#34 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#33 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:63
#32 Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession:handle in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#31 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#30 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php:37
#29 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse:handle in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#28 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#27 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:59
#26 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies:handle in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#25 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#24 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:102
#23 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:612
#22 Illuminate\Routing\Router:runRouteWithinStack in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:571
#21 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:549
#20 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:176
#19 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
#18 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php:56
#17 Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies:handle in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#16 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#15 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:30
#14 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#13 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#12 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:30
#11 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#10 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php:27
#8 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize:handle in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#7 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#6 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:46
#5 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode:handle in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#4 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#3 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:102
#2 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:151
#1 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:sendRequestThroughRouter in /var/www/Laravel/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:116
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:handle in /var/www/Laravel/default/public/index.php:58
```

Comment: You should be writting 2 routes for same action. Change 'tasks' to 'layouts.tasks' anyways

Comment: Do you have any other routes? If you have multiple routes, and they both match, the first one in the routes file will "win".  Maybe you still have the original '/' welcome route *above* your new tasks route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change the content of your `routes/web.php` from 
`Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); });`
To 
`Route::get('/', 'YourControllerName@functionName');`

Then in the Controller:

```
public function functionName(){
$tasks = Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

    return view('layouts.tasks', [
        'tasks' => $tasks
    ]);
}
```

Alternatively in the same file web.php you can do:

```
Route::get('/', function () { 
$tasks = \DB::table('tasks')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
return view('layouts.tasks', [
        'tasks' => $tasks
    ]); 

});
```

Hope that help

Comment: Unfortunately that still didn't help... I've tried both combinations of adding the "layouts." in the view definition, and moving the `tasks.blade.php` file a level up from the `layouts` folder. There must be something more missing...

Comment: Can you show the content of your route file `routes/web.php`

Comment: `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});` That file wasn't even mentioned in the tutorial, how come they didn't consider it relevant?

Comment: That's where you have the error from. change this `return view('welcome')` to `return view('layouts.tasks')` I will update my response to load the view from controller

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('layouts.tasks', [
    'tasks' => $tasks
]);
```

Because your view in inside folder i.e layouts

Answer (score 0):

You didn't miss anything but you need to replace tasks with return layouts.tasks' in view function.

```
return view('layouts.tasks', [
    'tasks' => $tasks
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a web.php file, make sure you place all your routes there

also, i got the same issue as you and resolved it by clearing route cache
run

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just solved it. running this command should help:

`php artisan optimize:clear`

It clears all cache.

more information here: https://dev.to/kenfai/laravel-artisan-cache-commands-explained-41e1